# onSelect option with get request

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, axios

I want to send params to my function and have a list:

```html
<select>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

so how can I send params each time to the function, function(*selected value*) and use it as axios.get param?

```html
export function loadDetail(*selected value*) {
    return (dispatch) => {...
```

Should I use onSelect? Cause look's like I don't use it correctly.

Comment: I think you want onchange event.

Comment: I think it's onChange that you want and you can also show how you are using it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it on select, add a `onChange` event on the select and get `e.target.value` from the event parameter which is passed from this event.

`function loadDetail(event) {
    let value = event.target.value
    ...`

(If you doesn't want it on change, retrieve the value with DOM in the corpse of your function `document.querySelector('#mySelect').value`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [onchange event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) or [oninput event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp)

```js
function myFunction(event){
console.log("Selected Value:",event.currentTarget.value)
}
```

```html
<select  onchange="myFunction(event)">
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```